# How do I move items from one list to another?

Tags: python

I am trying to remove all the items from list2 into list1 like this:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]

for item in l2:
    l1.append(item)
    l2.remove(item)
```

the problem is:

```
#l1 now returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
#l2 now returns [5]
```

I want it so that:

```
#l1 returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
#l2 returns []
```

Why does this happen? And what is the conventional way to achieve what I'm trying to do, in Python?

Comment: Simplest (and fastest) way to go would be `l1.extend(l2); l2.clear()`

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you are [removing items while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating).

For your problem - moving all items from one list to another list - the best solution is to use built-in methods provided by lists (the latter since Python 3.3):

```py
l1.extend(l2)
l2.clear()
```

you can replace `l2.clear()` with `l2 = []` if there are no other references to `l2`